# Returning to homepage after login causes Action Controller Exception in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've created an authentication system using Rails. While my login and signup forms are working as expected, I've hit the following glitch:

When a user logs in,he's redirected to his profile page. Now if I close the tab and then access the site's homepage an exception is raised by Action Controller: `undefined method for nil:NilClass`.My system checks whether a user is logged in and then changes the urls accordingly. Hence when the user is logged out, the homepage opens correctly.

I believe this is due to the instance variable of my User model (i.e. @user) not being available at the home page. How to resolve this issue?

For reference, here's my header partial which is causing the trouble:

```
<div class="header">
   <div class="nav">
       <div class="container">
           <% if logged_in? %>
             <ul class= "nav-left">
                 <li><%= link_to @user.name, "#" %></li>
             </ul>

             <ul>
                 <li><%= link_to "Explore Communities", "#" %></li>
                 <li><%= link_to "Logout", logout_path, method:"delete" %></li>
             </ul>
               <% else %>
         <h1 class="left"> <%= link_to "Social Media", root_path %> </h1>
        <button class="hamburger">&#9776;</button>


        <ul class="right"> 
            <li> <%= link_to "Login", login_path %></li>
            <li> <%= link_to "Signup", signup_path %> </li>
        </ul>


     </div>
     <% end %>
 </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can try using `if @user` as your check to see if they are logged in (assuming @user is populated by the signed in user).  I think calling methods on that while they are signed out leading to your method for nil errors

Comment: @Jared Well I've implemented a 'remember me' scheme. So sessions should persist, right? In addition going to hompageurl/users/id works perfectly.

Comment: Yea, my usual setup to see if a user is logged in is to have `@current_user`.  Do you have a stacktrace or the line of code specifically it is erroring on?

Comment: @Jared That's what was I was doing wrong. I was checking if `@user` is logged in. I corrected it and it works now. Thanks for the pointer.